# How can I completely remove the KDE 5.6 Plasma desktop from Ubuntu 16.04 and restore Unity?

Tags: unity, kde

I have installed the Plasma 5.6 desktop over Unity to give a try, but I don't really like it and I want to completely remove  Plasma 5.6 and restore Unity.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Removing a desktop environment completely is never recommended, since it can break packages that Ubuntu or other DEs depend on. In fact, it's not really recommended that you install a second DE in the first place. If you install a DE, you should really be prepared to either reinstall Ubuntu or just keep the DE installed.

You can use the command below to remove most/all of the Kubuntu/Plasma/KDE packages. **Please keep in mind that things can break.**

```
sudo apt-get purge '^kde' '^kubuntu' '^plasma'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It removed the plasma desktop from the login screen, however still some kde native apps are still installed. Also the Kubuntu splash screen while restarting it's still displaying. Any idea how to deal with this? Thanks.

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`, selecting `lightdm` when prompted. For the leftover apps, you need to remove those manually.

Comment: That command did not, however I hae used the following:                         sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: As you said.... things are broken and therefore I think I have to reinstall all of it again... ;-(

Comment: you might want to add '^akonadi' to this

Answer (score 1):

I used Synaptic package manager and typed KDE , went to the installed apps in the sidebar ,marked everything KDE and completely removed them .
Lost KDE connect , but i can install it again  .
It's not very profissional , but it did the job.
Hope it helps .