# How do I completely remove KDE and nothing left behind?

Tags: mouse, kde, 17.04, cursor

I have installed Kubuntu on my PC as a dual boot to dual boot Windows and Kubuntu but I decided to get rid of Kubuntu and replace it with Ubuntu by using:

`sudo apt-get remove Kubuntu-Desktop`

and

`sudo apt-get install Ubuntu-Desktop`

When I booted back into Ubuntu I still had a lot of programs and junk I don't need anymore from KDE and I tried several methods on the internet to find a way to fix this issue. I also tried fix why the mouse cursor when loading sometimes switched to the KDE loading cursor. I even reinstalled the normal Ubuntu cursor theme to get it to stop switching to the KDE loading cursor and reinstalled the `ubuntu-desktop` to see if it would stop the cursor bug and would delete the junk left over.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829125/how-can-i-completely-remove-the-kde-5-6-plasma-desktop-from-ubuntu-16-04-and-res) and see if it does that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all traces of KDE installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79636/how-to-remove-all-traces-of-kde-installed)

Answer (score 0):

If you have personal files you want to keep, backup your personal files from your `/home` folder.  Then run the Ubuntu LiveUSB installer.  Install Ubuntu on the partition that has the KDE installed.

Since you say you have a dual boot with Windows and KDE, you'll be able to easily identify the KDE partition by the partition type, `ext4`.

The fresh install process will remove all the systemwide folders and replace all the Libraries and settings for Ubuntu.

When you perform the install, you'll have an option to format the partition or install to the partition without formatting.  If you use the latter (install to the partition without formatting) it won't touch your `/home` folder.  It'll just do as you asked for, completely remove KDE and have it replaced with Ubuntu.

You're find the option for picking the previous (kde) partition under the **Something Else** install choice.